# React – how to render additional component inside another mounted one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Just wonder are there any approaches to render component in another component in React.

I render a `<Scene />` component like this:

```
import Scene from './Scene';

ReactDOM.render(<Scene/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And at some point I need to render another component `<Building />` (for example on `onClick`) so that it should be inside `<Scene />`

At the current I'm trying to do so like this:

```
import Building from './Building';

ReactDOM.render(<Building/>, document.getElementById('fields'));
```

And this `fields` container inside this `render()` method is a child (pretty deep one) of `<Scene />`

Yes, it renders, it's located inside `#fields` in HTML, but if I go to React developer tools I see this:

```
<Scene></Scene>
<Building></Building>
```

React just rendering `<Building>` outside of `<Scene>` and I need quite the opposite.

Unfortunately, conditional rendering isn't the case.

Comment: You might wanna use portals : https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only use one `ReactDOM.render()`, not multiple. It's common to create 1 component (often named `<App />`) and in that component you create logic. Basically, you create *the whole app* in Javascript/ReactJS, and you use that line to "load" it into your html.

```
export class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        // It now returns only one component, but this is where you would put your react router
        return(
            <Scene />
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));


export class Scene extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <>
                <div> Your normal scene here and if you want <Building /></div>
                { orSomeVariableWhichHasToBeTrue && <Building />}
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

---

Also, I suggest trying to follow their Basics tutorial, I think you're missing the way React's intended use. Reading the Doc's again might help for some insights.